# C# вирусная часть кода

Tags: c#, virustotal

Всем привет. Пишу приложение которое должно запускать процесс и инжектить в неё dll библиотеку. В целом я это сделал, но дело в virustotal, он показывает что в приложении есть вирусы.

Как можно сделать инжект библиотеки в процесс скрытно от антивирусов?

Код инжектора:

```
    // inject method
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        uint nSize,
        out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        uint dwStackSize,
        IntPtr lpStartAddress,
        IntPtr lpParameter,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpThreadId);

    // privileges
    const int PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002;
    const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
    const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;
    const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
    const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

    // used for memory allocation
    const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;

    const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000;
    const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool IsWow64Process(
        [In] IntPtr hProcess,
        [Out] out bool wow64Process
    );

    public static int DoInject(string dllPath, Process tProcess)
    {
        Process targetProcess = tProcess;
        string dllName = dllPath;
        IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, targetProcess.Id);
        IntPtr loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
        IntPtr allocMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
        UIntPtr bytesWritten;
        WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllName), (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), out bytesWritten);
        CreateRemoteThread(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddr, allocMemAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @aepot Знаешь что-нибудь по этому поводу?

Comment: А как можно назвать инжект по-другому, как не вирус? Если такое делается, то это нелегальные действия, которые влияют на изначальный продукт и в 90% это читы, вирусы, взломы. Так что правильно все вирустотал пишет, написали вирус, получайте и результат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ То есть вариантов вообще нет никаких?

Comment: Даже если и есть, то скажите, какой смысл вам говорить, как ломать чужие продукты/pc без палева? Я лично против вообще существования подобного. Это если бы вы сейчас удумали убийство, и спрашивали у знакомых как лучше это провернуть. Также и тут, вы задумали явно что-то не очень хорошее и просите у людей вам посадействовать в этом.

Comment: Если вы делаете зловред, то никто вам не поможет. Если делаете полезную прогу для расширения функциональности другого продукта, то пользователь вашего приложения сам внесёт его в исключения антивируса.

Comment: я использовал похожий код лет 6-8мь назад, очень хотелось выводить картинку с камеры в WinCC, но писать Active-X и регистрировать его в системе на куче компов было очень лень. Использовал похожий подход. Загружал длл в пространство процесса, потом перечислял все окна искал текст по шаблону, если находил, то выводил туда видео с помощью SDK производителя камеры. Оно даже работало несколько лет, из побочных эффектов при закрытии окна скады процесс крашился с ошибкой доступа к памяти.

Comment: Если антивирус реагирует эвристикой, то переделка кода и перестановка порядка вызова функций не поможет. Только замена общеизвестных функций таких как WriteProcessMemory и CreateRemoteThread, на менее распространенные аналоги т.к. скорее всего реагирует он именно на них. так же может помочь цифровая подпись приложения, тогда сертификат можно добавить в исключения антивирусного ПО и спокойно обновлять код приложения внутри компании не опираясь на хэши.

Comment: С год назад у меня каспер снес приложение которое писали лет 15 назад на дельфи, и видимо там была толи версия компилятора старая, толи еще что-то, но в общем из-за того, что один из сотрудников подключил себе диск с бэкапами хранилки как сетевой в один прекрасный день антивирус просто взял и удалил все копии приложения со всех ПК где нашел его, и восстановить из карантина не дал. Я остался без оного. Благо его не используют уже лет десять как, но осадочек остался.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не собирался ничего ломать. Я пишу запускатор (лаунчер) для игры, она требует инжект библиотеки мультиплеера в себя. Зря я это не написал в потоке.

Comment: Это чтож за игра такая... Создавал кучу серверов по куче игр и не встречал необходимости инжектить dll. В любом случае, это взлом, ибо как еще назвать то, что не предусмотрено разработчиками этой игры, но сделано через костыль сторонними людьми?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Игра GTA San Andreas, мультиплеер SA:MP. Да, именно так там устроен запуск мультиплеера. Запускается gta_sa.exe с параметрами и инжектится в неё samp.dll. Не всегда инжект считается взломом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вы не правильно поставили вопрос:** надо не "как спрятаться от антивируса?", это может говорить о том, что вы пишете сомнительный код, а надо спрашивать "как понять, на что именно ругается антивирус?". Вы ведь не пишете ничего опасного, правда? Если это не так, можете удалить свой вопрос, на StackOverflow подобный код не приветствуется.

У меня самого каталог с C# репозиториями находится в исключениях антивируса.

**Правило**

Если ваш код детектится антивирусной программой как зараза, это значит, что существует зараза, в которой имеется кодовая сигнатура, найденная у вас.

**Варианты действий**

Как ни странно, прятать подобное от антивируса - смысла мало, он все равно найдет, пройдется эвристикой, расшифрует, и т.д. В последний раз я получил срабатывание Symantec антивируса на приложение, которое просто использует `WebBrowser`, чтобы выполнить некий сценарий в админке моего сайта. У меня вообще ни одного `P/Invoke` вызова в приложении не было.

А избавился я от сработки просто сделав код более лаконичным и менее запутанным. Как только я прорефакторился и избавился от костылей, антивирус перестал ругаться. Получается, что если не прячешься, а наоборот пишешь открыто и линейно с минимумом запутанности, антивирус реагирует на не опасный код с меньшей вероятностью.

В вашем же случае реально используются опасные операции, которые используются зловредами. Попробуйте обезвредить свой код, например, сделайте его неполноценным, чтобы ругаться перестало, затем смотрите, что убрали. Затем как найдете, что именно делает ваш код "вредоносным", уже ищите, как это исправить.

False Positive у антивирусов - обычное дело. Но здесь не надо ничего прятать, если конечно вы не пишете вредоносный код, здесь наоборот надо быть максимально простым и открытым. В линейном коде антивирусу проще разобраться, и понять, что ваш код не представляет опасности.

Comment: У меня каспер ругался на 3 строки кода в пауэршеле. Алгоритм был прост до безобразия. получить список процессов. найти имя нужного, если процесс работает послать запрос серверу на остановку опроса на определенное время. причем при проверке скрипта антивирусом он не ругался. Но стоило только его добавить в планировщик заданий винды, как все тут же вирус с удалением задания и файла. и с падением консоли планировщика. Пару недель потом спаппорт каспера мучал пока они не исправили косяк. На что антивирус в 3х строках кода на PS так реагировал они мне так и не ответили.

Comment: Я занимаюсь написанием запускатора (лаунчера) для игры, которая требует в себя инжект библиотеки мультиплеера, зря я об этом не написал в потоке.
А как же можно сделать функцию инжекта открытой и прямолинейной?
Я пробовал разные методы инжекта, простые и трудные, мой результат 6/70 virustotal это максимум (хотелось бы 0)

Comment: @waparabka на этот вопрос невозможно ответить объективно, задача не простая и творческая. К сожалению, я не могу сделать ответ лучше, чем то что есть. В идеале, лучше обойтись конечно без инжекта вообще, например доработать игру.