# C# вредоносный участок кода

Tags: c#

Уже какой день пытаюсь разобраться с детектом антивирусов своего приложения, и в целом, успешно. Но не могу додумать что делать с кодом, который отвечает за автообновление приложения.

Есть предположения что антивирусы детектят конкретно Process.Start(); функцию, либо Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(); убрав код автообновления из программы показатель на вирустотал 0/70.

App.Xaml.cs

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (SelfUpdate())
            return;

        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

        if (args.Length > 1)
        {
            while (Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileName(args[1])).Length > 1)
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            
            File.Delete(args[1]);
            File.Move(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName), args[1]);
        }

        App application = new App();
        application.InitializeComponent();
        application.Run();
    }

    private static bool SelfUpdate()
    {
        XmlDocument Xml = new XmlDocument();
        Xml.Load("launcherPatch.xml"); //хэш актуального приложения

        string actualHash = Xml.GetElementsByTagName("hash")[0].InnerText;
        string clientHash = string.Empty;
        
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName)))
            {
                byte[] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                clientHash = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", string.Empty);
            }
        }
        
        if (!clientHash.Equals(actualHash))
        {
            using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
            {
                string UpdatedFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Replace(".exe", ".tmp.exe"));

                Client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Process.Start(UpdatedFilePath, "\"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\"");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                };

                //ссылка на скачивание обновлённого приложения
                Client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("launcherBuild.exe"), UpdatedFilePath);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: [Вот пара советов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182080/373567), а вообще сделайте нормальный пакет установки `.msi`, а не `.exe`. Здесь еще можно допилить все это до ума, но неизвестно, сработает ли. Я чуть позже попробую дописать.

Comment: Я писал в касперский и мне ответили что срабатывание ложное, предложили писать им каждый раз после апдейта приложения, но я не нахожу этот вариант подходящим. Помимо касперского есть ещё 3 антивируса: Ikarus, ZoneAlarm by Check Point и Microsoft. Двое жалуются на Trojan, другие двое на UDS:DangerousObject.Multi.Generic.

Comment: Стоп, а откуда ваш `WebClient` скачивает файл?

Comment: Отсюда файл скачивается: https://smartrp.by/launcher/launcherBuild.exe
Если интересно что на вирустотале: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/7171a70762576f51900993d7b175ecbfd4415b3b474007597774cb8a04372482/detection

Comment: Сейчас попробовал поменять строчку string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

На string[] args = new string[10]; ради теста, результат на вирустотал 1/70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Моя попытка немного привести ваш код во порядок.

```cs
[STAThread]
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    if (await SelfUpdate())
        return;

    if (args.Length > 1)
    {
        while (Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileName(args[1])).Length > 1) // здесь лучше переписать на FileSystemWatcher
            await Task.Delay(200);

        File.Delete(args[1]);
        File.Move(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName), args[1]);
    }

    App application = new App();
    application.InitializeComponent();
    application.Run();
}

private static async Task<bool> SelfUpdate()
{
    XmlDocument Xml = new XmlDocument();
    Xml.Load("launcherPatch.xml"); //хэш актуального приложения

    string actualHash = Xml.GetElementsByTagName("hash")[0].InnerText;
    string clientHash = string.Empty;

    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName)))
    {
        byte[] checksum = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        clientHash = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }

    if (clientHash != actualHash)
    {
        string UpdatedFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Replace(".exe", ".tmp.exe"));
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var fs = File.Create(UpdatedFilePath))
        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://smartrp.by/launcher/launcherBuild.exe"))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
        Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = UpdatedFilePath, UseShellExecute = true } };
        process.Start();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ты очень мне помог этой строкой: public static void Main(string[] args)
Теперь показатель на вирустотале 1/70, с твоим кодом правда 2/70, но всё же.

Comment: @waparabka внес еще маленькую правочку. `await stream.CopyToAsync(fs)`.

Comment: @waparabka еще посмотрите [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230878/373567), так можно передавать информацию между процессами, чтобы не дергать API Process.